# How to know how many questions there are in a Confluence Questions database?

Tags: confluence

I'm using [Confluence Questions](https://es.atlassian.com/software/confluence-questions/) as a knowledgebase for my team. Although there is a stats page, I cannot seem to find simply how many questions are in the database at a given moment.

The stats are about how many questions per week, answers peer week, and so on, but it seems there is not a metric for how many total questions there are.

How can I find out the total number of questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it. Questions are nothing but another type of content in conflunce. So, if you go to the content search and filter by the custom type "Question", you can see how many questions there are:

[image]

To see just the question count, you can leave the search box empty, and pay attention to the results legend:

[image]

In this example, there are 55 questions in the database.